# Troubles on constructing HLS using libp2p-http

Tags: http, go, http-live-streaming, libp2p, go-libp2p

I intend to implement a classic HLS example with libp2p, which is as follows
https://hackernoon.com/building-a-media-streaming-server-using-go-and-hls-protocol-j85h3wem
But I encountered the following errors：

> 404 page not found

My code constructing linstening:

```
m1, _ := multiaddr.NewMultiaddr("/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/1000")
    m2, _ := multiaddr.NewMultiaddr("/ip4/127.0.0.1/tcp/1001")
    srvHost := NewHost(m1)
    clientHost := NewHost(m2)
    defer srvHost.Close()
    defer clientHost.Close()

    srvHost.Peerstore().AddAddrs(clientHost.ID(), clientHost.Addrs(), peerstore.PermanentAddrTTL)
    fmt.Println("id is", clientHost.ID())
    fmt.Println("addr is", srvHost.Addrs())
    clientHost.Peerstore().AddAddrs(srvHost.ID(), srvHost.Addrs(), peerstore.PermanentAddrTTL)

    listener, err := gostream.Listen(srvHost, "/testiti-test")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer listener.Close()
```

My code constructing client:

```
tr := &http.Transport{}
    tr.RegisterProtocol("libp2p", p2phttp.NewTransport(clientHost, p2phttp.ProtocolOption("/testiti-test")))
client := &http.Client{Transport: tr}

res, err := client.Get(fmt.Sprintf("libp2p://%s/simple", port))
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
defer res.Body.Close()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(data))
```

My code constructing sever:

```
go func() {
        http.HandleFunc("/simple", addHeaders(http.FileServer(http.Dir(songsDir))))
        //http.HandleFunc("/simple", addHeaders2())
        fmt.Printf("Starting server on %v\n", port)
        log.Printf("Serving %s on HTTP port: %v\n", songsDir, port)

        server := &http.Server{}
        server.Serve(listener)
    }()
func addHeaders(h http.Handler) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
}
```

New host:

```
func NewHost(listen multiaddr.Multiaddr) host.Host {
    h, err := libp2p.New(
        libp2p.ListenAddrs(listen),
    )
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return h
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is casued by routing.For a http.FileServer,"\simple" means a dir but   not a url.So just fix like this:

```
url := fmt.Sprintf("libp2p://%s/origin.m3u8", port)
res, err := client.Get(url)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)
defer res.Body.Close()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(data))
```